# transações concorrentes spring boot + docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, transações, concorrência

Tenho uma aplicação no [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) com JHipster(Spring Boot + Angular) onde gero protocolos para atendimento.

Estou usando o `@Transactional` na classe de gerar os Protocolos para controle na geração das transações porém estou tendo problemas ainda de **dados duplicados devido a quantidade de pessoas usando a aplicação ao mesmo tempo**. Pensei em uma implementação de tabela para controle onde guardaria a data e quantidade de vagas pré-selecionadas.

Como segunda opção encontramos o Apache Kafta para ajudar no controle das transações.

Quem tiver uma ideia melhor para controle das transações visto que as mesmas ficam de forma distribuídas fico no aguardo.

Código :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProtocoloService {

    private final AgendamentoRepository agendamentoRepository;

    public ProtocoloService(AgendamentoRepository agendamentoRepository) {
        this.agendamentoRepository = agendamentoRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public String gerar() {

        return gerar(getInicial());
    }

    private String gerar(String inicial) {
        List<Agendamento> agendamentoList = agendamentoRepository.findAgendamentoByProtocoloStartingWith(inicial);
        if(agendamentoList.isEmpty()) {
            return inicial + "000001";
        } else {
            Agendamento maior = agendamentoList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Agendamento::getProtocolo)).get();
            Long numeral = Long.valueOf(maior.getProtocolo().substring(6))+1;
            return inicial + StringUtils.leftPad(String.valueOf(numeral), 6, "0");
        }
    }

    private String getInicial() {
        String ano = String.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getYear()).substring(2);
        String mes = StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getMonthValue()),2,"0");
        String dia = StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth()),2,"0");
        return ano+mes+dia;
    }
}
```

Comment: Voce disse que esta tendo problemas, pode ser mais específicos com os problemas, citar todos eles(alem do problema de concorrencia)?, Voce citou a palavras Vagas, eu nao entendi o contexto. Qual a estrutura da distribuição da sua aplicação?, Qual a versão do spring boot?

Comment: @ErickLuz editado, mas o título já cita o problema...